# How to write a Regular Expression for integer 14 digits fix and first digit can be 1 or 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project where the user must fill a form which contain a 14 digits element.

I need to check if the user input is an integer of 14 digits (min 14 digits, max 14 digits) with the first digit 1 or 2.

Can you please help me with a regular expression.

I tried this for 14 digits :  `[RegularExpression(@"^\d{14}$")]` but is not working, I mean It see that I must enter 14 digits but does not let me saved into database.

the property which I need to fill is:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{14}$")]
public int CNP { get; set; }
```

Comment: 14 digits in an Int32 ?

Comment: An `int` only has a range -2147483648 to 2147483647 so 14 digits would not be valid.

Comment: You question title and body do not match. Are you facing problem with regex itself or arithmetic issue?

Comment: I changed my property to decimal, and now is working fine, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@"^[12]\d{13}$"
```

The `[12]` ensures only `1` or `2` appear at the beginning of the string. See [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for more info.